# It's possible to decode this string?

Tags: javascript, base64, uri, decode

I found this site:
https://www.liveappsearch.com/cl.php?id=739ba6751f127e8039c0bb7f2fa69e94

This url have content locker on id "739ba6751f127e8039c0bb7f2fa69e94"

Content locker load function https://www.liveappsearch.com/contentlockers/load.php?f=1&a=&id=739ba6751f127e8039c0bb7f2fa69e94

My question is it's possible to decode this string "739ba6751f127e8039c0bb7f2fa69e94"?

Any content locker has a unique id on this site, I wonder it's a random string generated by the server to detect locker, 
or a string that can be decoded like

739ba6751f127e8039c0bb7f2fa69e94 = 1112 or abba

h12h321h3uh1h23h12h3h12h32h13h21 = 1113 or abbb

How should I search, can it be decoded? Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's hex to me. Unless you see a character out of the range `0-F`. Did you try hex? Why did you think base64?

Comment: Hey, i think it's a  base64 because second locker if it exists
 (in url_redirect conterlocker.load ) it's a base64 code. I try hex decode and this is result = s¦u~9À»/¦ it's a normal?

Comment: Normal for a binary value?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, i try to decode string to hex, and i get hex code, but it does not tell me anything :(

Comment: I need to create string to hex or to binary?

Comment: Why do you expect it to "tell you anything"? It's a number.

Comment: Ok so when i decode string to hex and get like s¦u~9À»/¦ result it's a content locker unique id before encoding?

Comment: Ups, sorry when i convert string to hex i get 3733396261363735316631323765383033396330626237663266613639653934, previously i convert hex to text. This is a unique id before encoding?

Comment: `System.out.println(new BigInteger("739ba6751f127e8039c0bb7f2fa69e94", 16));` - I get `153669401687643837365314288227981893268` ... but whatever... it's a big number.

Comment: Uh, ok, i trying decode content locker id to detect all scams from this site, maybe it's a just random number generated by server to get unique id. I have to look further if it is actually possible to decode